# Question on members in derived classes (new vs override)

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding

I'm working through the Head First Design Patterns book and am currently on the Decorator Pattern chapter. Since the book examples are written in Java, I'm adapting the, to C# as I go.

This example simulates a coffee shop ordering system. There is an abstract base class for `Beverage` and subclasses for specific beverages (ex: `Espresso`). The decorator classes are used to add condiments and drink modifications. There is an abstract class `CondimentDecorator` that derives from `Beverage` and then subclasses like `Mocha` for the individual decorators. Gist with all files: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/67e4fe5fe0477d34b24125f741ad0b3a

My question - in the base `Beverage` class, the description string is set to "Unknown beverage". The constructor for a specific drink sets this to the drink name - so if I use:

```
Beverage espresso = new Espresso();
Console.WriteLine($"{espresso.GetDescription()}");
```

It responds with "Espresso". Now, when using the decorator, the `GetDescription` method is overridden, in the `Mocha` class it adds "Mocha" after the beverage's description.

```
public override string GetDescription()
{
    return beverage.GetDescription() + " Mocha";
}
```

If I use the `override` modifier in CondimentDecorator.cs:

```
public abstract override string GetDescription();
```

This works as expected. I run:

```
Beverage espresso = new Espresso();
Console.WriteLine($"{espresso.GetDescription()}"); // Espresso
espresso = new Mocha(espresso);
Console.WriteLine($"{espresso.GetDescription()}"); // Espresso Mocha
```

However, if I change the modifier to `new` in CondimentDecorator.cs like this:

```
public abstract new string GetDescription();
```

And run the same code, I get the below results:

```
Beverage espresso = new Espresso();
Console.WriteLine($"{espresso.GetDescription()}"); // Espresso
espresso = new Mocha(espresso);
Console.WriteLine($"{espresso.GetDescription()}"); // Unknown beverage
```

I'm a little confused why this happens...since `GetDescription` is being called in Mocha like this...

```
public override string GetDescription()
{
    return beverage.GetDescription() + " Mocha";
}
```

...and beverage is a reference back to the original espresso object, why doesn't the code pick up on the description that was set when `Espresso` was instantiated? The way I understand this, `new` would hide the original `GetDescription` method in the base class while `override` would extend that method. I'm not sure why that would effect which description the program reads -- the "unknown beverage" of `Mocha`, which gets that value from the `Beverage` class it derives from, or the "Espresso" of the beverage object I created that had the description set in the constructor.

I'm sure I'm just misunderstanding something basic about inheritance and how the new and override keywords work, if anyone can shed a little light on this I'd appreciate it!

Thanks!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399127/difference-between-new-and-override

Comment: In my experience, a `new` keyword with a method or property is most often wrong. Hardly anyone understands it, though there might be some rare uses for it. E.g. for our green field projects, I configured the Jenkins build to treat all warnings as errors. One of my colleagues used the same function name in a base class and its derived class which caused a fail. How did he fix that? By taking the suggestion of the compiler. Now the "bug in waiting" was changed to a real bug - the real solution was `virtual`for the base class and `òverride`in the derived class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusing thing about `new` is that it creates a second method with the same name as an existing method.

Let's talk about this line of code:

```
public abstract new string GetDescription();
```

Thanks to this code, `CondimentDecorator` now has *two* `GetDescription` methods: it has

- `GetDescription`, inherited from `Beverage`, and also
- `GetDescription`, newly declared in `CondimentDecorator`.

Now, whenever you call `GetDescription`, the compiler has to decide *which* `GetDescription` method to call. It does this by looking at the declared type of the variable that you're calling the method on (not the runtime type). If the declared type is `Beverage`, it calls the method which is inherited from `Beverage`; if the declared type is `CondimentDecorator`, it calls the method that's newly declared in `CondimentDecorator`.

Let's look at your calling code now:

```
Beverage espresso = new Espresso();
Console.WriteLine($"{espresso.GetDescription()}"); // Espresso
espresso = new Mocha(espresso);
Console.WriteLine($"{espresso.GetDescription()}"); // Unknown beverage
```

What is happening is that since the declared type of the `espresso` variable is `Beverage`, the compiler always interprets this as a call to the `GetDescription` method which is inherited from `Beverage`. The fact that the *runtime* type of `espresso` is `Mocha` doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me sort this out in my head -- it's starting to make a bit of sense now :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this article explains it:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx

Basically it depends on whether your beverage is being accessed as a Mocha or and Expresso vs what it actually is.

Assume you have a simple case where

Mocha : Espresso

then

((Espresso)mocha).GetDescription()  == "espresso" if you 'new' rather than 'override'

so if you want to do

```
foreach(Beverage b in List) 
{
    //print description
}
```

then you should override

Now your particular example is complicated by your decorator. which also inherits from beverage.

you have

Espresso : Beverage

and

Mocha : Decorator : Beverage

so when you use 'new' on Mocha but call

((Beverage)mocha).GetDescription()

you get the Beverage result "unknown beverage"

Comment: Thank you for the useful comment, the casting example you used helped me start thinking about this in the right way...